# How to run the "cat" command on the background inside the script

Tags: shell, background, scripting, cat

I have a USB LTE modem connected to my Raspberry and I need to read replies sent via serial line, generated by requests sent using the "echo" command. 
Example:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 &>> /ttyUSB0_logs &
echo "AT+csq" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+cgreg=2" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+cgreg?" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The problem is, although the "cat" command should run on the background and all output is directed to the file, script still freezes at this point. If I use the first command outside of the script, it works as I expect - it stores all output to the file ttyUSB0_logs on the background and I can use the received data for other operations. The question is - how can I integrate the first command to the script to get it work this way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you want:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 >> /ttyUSB0_logs &
```

if that doesn't work, you should double check what is actually freezing.  you can put `set -x` at the top of the script to get tracing output.

Comment: Thank you for the advice with `set -x` ! Now I see, the `cat` just doesn't send any output to the file (path was wrong in the example, the proper command should be `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > ttyUSB0_logs &` . Sorry for the mistake. But anyway, I still cant get over this - the process still runs, I can see it in `ps` output, but it just doesn't do the same thing as when I run it separately.